Question regarding making the subsets of a set G a G-set by left translation
I am currently going through Bergman's notes for Lang algebra and came across this statement:

If $G$ is a finite group and $x$ any subset of $G$, then the isotropy subgroup $G_x$ of $x$ under left translation is the largest subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $x$ is a union of right cosets of $H$. In particular, the cardinality of $x$ is a multiple of the order of $G_x$

I guess I see how the first part is true just by using the definition $G_x = \{ g \in G \ | \ gx = x \}$ but I am really unsure about where the second statement came from. I'm not sure how to relate the cardinality of $x$ to the order of the isometry group.

From the first sentence, $x$ is a union of right cosets of $G_x$. So just as in the proof of Lagrange's theorem, distinct cosets are disjoint, so $|G_x|$ divides $|x|$.

Oh yes, obviously. Thank you very much
